# Wordpress - Nearby location - distance from the current location

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to WordPress. I need a solution for a WordPress site search function. My client has few shops at different places. I need a search functionality where the search will show nearby shop (filters the shop list) along with the distance from the current location.

Please let me know any existing plugins or GitHub projects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to look in to the google geolocation API.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I can use it in plain php, jqery. But I'm looking for a plugin or existing source that can make my things easier.